# Debugging in Delphi (RAD Studio) - viewing class properties in Watch List

Tags: visual-studio, delphi, debugging, ide

When I set breakpoint in code and I want to check properties of some class in RAD Studio 2009 (Delphi project) I cannot see them in Watch List or in Local Variables list.

All I see is **Pointer (Address) as TSomeClass**.

[image: Debugging in RAD Studio]

Why I see this? I use also Visual Studio where it is amazing - I can see Properties and all members of some class.

I am sure the same worked in some older versions of Delphi too (There was small [+] which could be expanded to see class properties).

[image: Visual Studio debug]

Is there some settings for this (I have turned off optimizations, turned on Debug...)

Maybe this is a trivial question but I am not able to continue with my project as this is really uncomfortable for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing like with like. The variable in the Delphi screenshot is an interface. It has no data members, only methods. The debugger won't call methods to display tooltips, etc. since methods can have side-effects. You don't want your tooltips changing the meaning of the program.

On the other hand, your VS example is a class with data members. These are displayed in the debugger nicely in VS, and in Delphi for that matter.

Comment: OK, so why I cannot see ProjectOptionsConfs.ActiveConfiguration := nil (first screen, first green arrow) if ActiveConfiguration is property? Or another: property ConfigurationCount: Integer ??

Comment: For the reason that I explained in the answer. An interface does not have data members. It only has methods. Methods can have side effects. You don't want tooltip evaluation to have side effects. I'm struggling to see how I could explain this any more clearly.

Comment: @Slappy They may be properties, but those properties are backed by methods. There is no way for Delphi to know whether those methods have side effects. So - _for your benefit_ - it won't automatically evaluate anything that _might_ change the behaviour of your program. There are a few ways to tell Delphi that "you know better" and force it to evaluate. E.g. Using "Debug Inspector" or "Watch Properties". But tooltips would be an extremely bad place to trigger side-effects.

Comment: OK, that sounds reasonable. Thanks!